# How can we warn the user if the application timeouts due to Idle-timeout set in the application pool of an ASP.NET MVC 4 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, session-timeout

In my `ASP.NET MVC 4` application I am using Forms Authentication and have set `session timeout` to be 600 minutes (10 hours) and `Forms Authentication timeout` to be 550 minutes. I’ve also set the `Idle-timeout of the application pool` used by this app to be 50 minutes.

If the app is idle for more than 50 minutes by one user and no other users are logged in (or the other logged in users are also not using the app for more than 5o minutes), the app is going to time out. In such scenario, I would like to warn the user - after 45 minutes have passed about the upcoming timeout so that a user can save their data, if he/she likes before the app time outs. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The very act of warning the user would generate traffic to/from the website, effectively refreshing the timeout and making the whole point of the exercise moot.  Why save data when it's no longer going to time out?

What's more, their session will get lost when the app pool shuts down, unless you're using a database oriented session.  So setting it to 10 hours isn't going to be absolute.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you can do about the app pool as it could go at any time. You could move your session provider into a database so that if the app pool shuts down and restarts (within your 10 hour period) your user will continue from the same session.

You could also have some javascript on a timeout for X hours to pop-up a message or warning. It would reset on each page load. Chances are, though, that if they've been inactive for 10 hours they won't be there to take action based on the message so you might be best just redirecting them to a page to say that their session has timed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can flip forms authentication into using a persisted authentication cookie so the users login is stored in a cookie that persists through browser sessions. "That cookie is encrypted using the servers machinekey in the web.config or machine.config"

In such a case it wouldn't matter if the app pool closed.  When the user accesses the site again it will spin back up, their cookie will get seen/processed by the Forms Authentication Http Module and they'll still be logged in and because they are logged in, should still be able to look up any data whether they saved it or not.

Secondly, if they have client side data they need to save, you should be keeping a connection open to the server "e.g. call a refresh method with a javascript timer via ajax or something".

You should never design your site to rely on data that is in w3wp.exe.  It should be designed so that w3wp.exe can close whenever it wants and spin back up and get back to where it was without any data loss.

Comment: Also, in your example...

How would your site handle a random windows update reboot, or an admin running an iisreset?  They would cause w3wp.exe's to all close outside of the timeout window.

Comment: per your advice, I tried the persistent cookie by setting the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, true);`But when I refresh the page after 20 minutes, it still expires after 20 minutes (the idle-timeout of application pool). What I may be missing?

Comment: Increase the timeout on the cookie and set the sliding expiration to refresh it.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443

Comment: Also if you are using Session State, switch it to database mode instead of in process.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx  In SqlServer mode session state data is stored in a sql database instead of a process.